# Reusable polymer iron-ajax custom element

Tags: polymer

I am new to Polymer. I would really appreciate the help if you guys know the answer. Let say i have a custom element called car-list.html that does nothing but call a REST API and bring back the car list. then i would like to call this custom element from different elements all over the site so i don't have to write the same code (iron-ajax) calling the same REST API 10 times throughout the site in 10 different elements. Please point me in a direction to read as i cant seem to find the answer.

Comment: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax

Comment: You could also have a look at [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta)